# VBA dynamic variable value

Tags: excel, vba

There is no dumb questions, only dumb people asking questions. I might fall in that category right now.

I want to achieve the following :

```
Sub test
Dim lastcolumn as long
lastcolumn = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
DebugPrint lastcolumn '=5
'Add 2 columns between first and last col
DebugPrint lastcolumn '=7
End Sub
```

right now I need to do as follow :

```
Sub test
Dim lastcolumn as long
lastcolumn = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
DebugPrint lastcolumn '=5
'Add 2 columns between first and last col
lastcolumn = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
DebugPrint lastcolumn '=7
End Sub
```

So I end up with

> lastcolumn = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column

all over the place

What's the correct way to do that?

Comment: unclear where you want to add the column. Inbetween the first and last column is not useful unless you only have 2 columns. If you have 10 columns, where do you want the new columns added?

Comment: The better way to find the last column is `lastcolumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

Comment: `lastColumn` stores the column number but is not updated when the sheet changes...

Comment: I'm sorry my question is not clear. it doesn't really matter where I insert the columns as long as it's between the first and the last. What I'm trying to do is for the "lastcolumn" to always "refresh" when I use it without having to always retype it. And I fully agree with your second comment.

Comment: That's not how a variable works.

Comment: @BigBen are you suggesting to use the `Change event` to always update `LastColumn` ? that might work I'll try!

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this ? Is it bad ? Might not be performant

```
'Option Explicit

Public Enum DynamicVar
    lastcolumn
    lastrow
End Enum

Public Function MyVar(name As DynamicVar) As Variant

If name = lastcolumn Then
    MyVar = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Exit Function

ElseIf name = lastrow Then
    MyVar = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Exit Function

End If

End Function

Sub test()
Cells(MyVar(lastrow), MyVar(lastcolumn)).value = "Wathever"
End Sub'
```

Edit : Maybe this is a bit better

```
Public Function MyVar(name As DynamicVar) As Variant

Select Case name

    Case lastcolumn
        MyVar = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Case lastrow
        MyVar = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

End Select

End Function
```